# Does data copied as text on a draft email in outlook travels over a network and can it be detected?

Tags: data-leakage

Is data saved as a draft email (not an attachment of a file) be detected over the network and what tools are used to prevent data leakage.

Comment: Are you talking about Outlook.com, Outlook365 or any other flavour?

Comment: I am talking about outlook.com

Comment: Can you log in to outlook.com in a different browser and see the draft email? I think you will find the answer yourself.

Comment: Well yes I can see the draft email from a different browser, can you please tell me if it can be detected over the network?

Comment: Is there any reading you done so far around this?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook.com is hosting the web interface AND the email data. Anything you write is sent to them, by the network. If you had a local email client like Outlook (or Thunderbird, or Eudora), then the drafts usually will be local and no data would be transfered by the network. Not in case of webmail: drafts are sent there via network and saved on their servers.

Can the data be detected? Depends on your network. If your network uses a SSL Termination Proxy, it can be visible on the gateway, but are policies and auditing to prevent anyone inspecting them at will. If your network does not employ a SSL Proxy, then no: data is protectd by SSL and readable only by your computer and Outlook server. And this (SSL) is what prevents data leakage.

Comment: Outlook stores drafts on the server by default. Other e-mail clients can be configured to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Well yes I can see the draft email from a different browser, can you please tell if it can be detected over the network?

It's obviously sent over the network. Outlook probably uses encryption to protect the message in transit, so only the receiving server can see the content of the message, or any metadata about it.

After it's saved the server admin can obviously see it as well. If you want to avoid that you will have to use a solution like S/MIME to encrypt the content of the e-mail.

Comment: So when a message is saved in a draft email the receiving server will be from the same network?

Comment: No, it will be the exchange server in use. This can be on any network.

Comment: So when the message is saving it is uploading and it will use the default network that I am uploading from and when the message is saved and downloads it uses any random exchange server that would most likely not be from the default server?

Comment: What are you actually wondering about, or what risk are you trying to protect against? If it's on premises exchange, there's a few clearly defined servers most likely. If it's cloud exchange, then it may be on any number of locations.

Comment: I accidentally stored some sensitive information in a draft email couple of months ago on my personal outlook account on a premises, they have data leakage software's in place but nothing really happened, I'm just concerned if something like this can still be detected right now or in the future and or if they have already detected this and have not approached me yet.

Comment: Then the answer is that it depends on the policies. They may only check outgoing mail, or they may have looked at it, and determined that nothing was actually sent. You should ask your employer when they do this check. Anyway, this check does most definitively not happen at the network layer - it happens at the application layer, e.g. the e-mail server, and any transport authentication is irrelevant.